# How to change ListViewItem placeholder color in UWP?

Tags: listview, uwp, placeholder, listviewitem, data-virtualization

For my UWP application I am using [**Random access data virtualization**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/listview-and-gridview-data-optimization#random-access-data-virtualization) with a **ListView**. My problem is, that for the content for this particular ListView the placeholders need to be white. In the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewitem#remarks) under Remarks there seem to the resource key **ListViewItemPlaceholderBackground**, however I can't figure out how to override it.

I have tried to implement a style resource for my **UserControl**:

**My UserControl**

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="SimplePdfViewer.SimplePdfViewerControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:SimplePdfViewer"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Unloaded="root_Unloaded"
    x:Name="root">

    <Grid>
        <!--ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"-->
        <!--ScrollViewer.ZoomMode="Disabled"-->
        <ListView x:Name="PdfListView" ItemsSource="{x:Bind DocumentDataSource}" ScrollViewer.ZoomMode="Enabled" ScrollViewer.IsScrollInertiaEnabled="True">

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="BitmapImage">
                    <ListViewItem Height="1200">
                        <Image Source="{x:Bind}"/>
                    </ListViewItem>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**Added Style Resource**

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="SimplePdfViewer.SimplePdfViewerControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:SimplePdfViewer"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Unloaded="root_Unloaded"
    x:Name="root">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem" x:Name="ListViewItemEdit">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <ListViewItemPresenter ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                        PlaceholderBackground="White"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <!--ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"-->
        <!--ScrollViewer.ZoomMode="Disabled"-->
        <ListView x:Name="PdfListView" ItemsSource="{x:Bind DocumentDataSource}" ScrollViewer.ZoomMode="Enabled" ScrollViewer.IsScrollInertiaEnabled="True">

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="BitmapImage">
                    <ListViewItem Height="1200" Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemEdit}">
                        <Image Source="{x:Bind}"/>
                    </ListViewItem>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I haven't found anything useful online; hopefully someone can help me out.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `x:Name` use `x:Key` in the style and then reference it from the `ItemContainerTemplate` property of the `ListView`:

```
<ListView ... ItemContainerTemplate="{StaticResource ListViewItemEdit}">
```

However, if you do it like this, you will have only partial functionality in the `ItemContainerTemplate`, which is not what you want. I would copy and paste the full `Style` from [docs here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299136.aspx) and then edit the color there. Or alternatively, you can just provide a custom version of the brush and not edit the container at all. Just delete the style and add this instead:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush Color="Blue" x:Key="ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

This should override the system's default color for this control.

Comment: I managed to color the placeholder white by using ItemContainerStyle in ListView; If I use <UserControl.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush Color="Blue" x:Key="ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush" />
</UserControl.Resources> do I have to do anything with the ListViewItem or just add it in the resources section

Comment: It should be enough just to add it, the resource system should pick it up when searching for the resource key